# Ramda with multi parameter and conditions

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I am newbie with the functional programming any one who can help me how can I convert this function to best functionality

```
const isNotNil = R.complement(R.isNil);
const isFunction = R.is(Function)

const a = (value, value2, fn) => {
   if (isNotNil(value)) {
     return isFunction(fn) ? fn(value) : value
   }
   return value2;
};

a(5,2, R.add(8))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ramda, you tend to pass the data that you want to operate on as the last parameter of a function. All other parameters could be seen as configuration for the process applied on the data.

Knowing this, your function signature should probably look like: `a(defaultValue, func, value)`

This allows you to build curried functions with predefined behaviour:

```js
const incOr42 = a(42, inc);
incOr42(1);    // 2
incOr42(null); // 42
```

Now let's look at breaking the problem into smaller pieces:

Firstly, let's validate `func`, that could be a function itself:

If the thing given to `checkFn` isn't a function, it returns a function that will always return its parameter. Otherwise it returns the original function

```js
const checkFn = unless(is(Function), always(identity));
checkFn(add(8))(5); // 13
checkFn('foo')(5);  // 5
```

Secondly let's build a function that accepts two parameters: `defaultValue` and `func`.
it will return a function that accept `value` and return either `defaultValue` if `value` is nil, or apply `func` to it otherwise:

```js
const a = useWith(ifElse(isNil), [always, checkFn]);
const incOr42 = a(42, inc);
incOr42(1);    // 2
incOr42(null); // 42
```

Putting everything together:

```js
const {unless, is, always, identity, ifElse, isNil, useWith, inc} = R;

const checkFn = unless(is(Function), always(identity));
const a = useWith(ifElse(isNil), [always, checkFn]);

const incOr42 = a(42, inc);

console.log(incOr42(1));
console.log(incOr42(null));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In FP, you should try to decompose concerns as much as possible, and avoid optional arguments and drive the flow using smaller pieces instead.

Also, Ramda is useful but lacks some data types like `Maybe` which could be really useful in this scenario. Take a look at [SanctuaryJS](https://sanctuary.js.org/).

The following code does exactly what you want using a purely functional approach

```js
const { toMaybe, maybe, pipe } = sanctuary

const a = f => value => value2 => pipe ([
    toMaybe, // converts to Just (value) or Nothing, when nil
    maybe (value2) (f) // if Nothing, value2, otherwise, value is passed to f
]) (value)

// Output: 3
const output1 = a (x => x + 1) (2) (4)
console.log ('output1: ', output1)

// Output: 4
const output2 = a (x => x + 1) (null) (4)
console.log ('output2: ', output2)
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/sanctuary@0.15.0"></script>
```

Note that I've not checked that `f` is a `Function`. JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language: just assume it's going to be a `Function`, and fail fast if it's not.

### Refactored approach to take advantage of partial application:

```js
const { toMaybe, maybe, pipe } = sanctuary

// Re-arranged parameters: now value is the latest one.
const a = f => value2 => pipe ([
    toMaybe, // converts to Just (value) or Nothing, when nil
    maybe (value2) (f) // if Nothing, value2, otherwise, value is passed to f
])

// Output: 3
const output1 = a (x => x + 1) (4) (2)
console.log ('output1: ', output1)

// Output: 4
const output2 = a (x => x + 1) (4) (null)
console.log ('output2: ', output2)
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/sanctuary@0.15.0"></script>
```

Comment: Is the dynamic nature of JavaScript a reason for not checking if a thing is a function? It seems a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: @customcommander At the end of the day, checking that is like trying to reproduce what a static type checker would do before going run-time. If your intended behavior requires a `Function`, it's the caller who's responsible of being sure what's being passed in.

Comment: @customcommander And, see what happens if `f` isn't a function: it throws an error. Otherwise, you're trying to mute an error that, sooner or later will produce a problem. Let's let the code fail as soon as possible. If you want a function, give a function: the other case is a bug.

Comment: In the OP initial attempt, the function is not applied to `value` if it isn't a function and will return `value` instead. Presumably the OP didn't want to let an error be thrown and perhaps the function was actually an optional parameter. Are you sort of implying that one should never validate any function parameters due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript? That seems like a dangerous statement to make.

Comment: @customcommander When you change your mind, you never build code that way. I suspect that the OP is trying to mute an error instead of facing it, so I gave my freedom to skip that part. Let's see what OP says about this approach...

Comment: @customcommander In FP you never use optional parameters: how do you take advantage of partial application otherwise? We need to build solutions as part of another mindset :D

Comment: The question asked how to "convert this to best functionality".  It's not at all clear if the OP was asking for how to rewrite the same functionality with more idiomatic Ramda code or wanted to determine how to make a more robust FP-style API.  I think you two are talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's at my own risk :D If OP doesn't want this, I'll drop my answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Actually, isn't this an XY problem?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: No, I was suggesting that you  both offered reasonalbe answers to slightly different interpretations of the question.

Comment: It could well be an XY problem.

Comment: My answer accepts the interpretation that @customcommander chose.  But yours is equally valid, and all can be reasonably considered answers to the question.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Right! Honestly, I believe that OP will improve his/her FP skills a bit, but I've doubts that it'll solve the underlying problem. I see imperative mindset behind OP's code, and probably the actual code might need an important refactor if it's plagued of optional parameters and manual type checks.

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that the OP's function doesn't make much sense. Why is the first argument applied to the optional function but the second isn't? Besides it is a good idea to point out to the OP that type introspection is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see much of a reason to go beyond the obvious.

This version seems to do precisely what you want, and is quite readable:

```js
const {is, isNil} = R

const a = (val, val2, fn) => isNil(val) ? val2 : is(Function, fn) ? fn(val) : val

console.log(a(5, 2, R.add(8)))       //=> 13
console.log(a(5, 2, 'NonAFunction')) //=> 5
console.log(a(null, 2, R.add(8)))    //=> 2
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Given that OP accepted @customcommander's answer, I feel that yours should be the accepted answer, because it's simpler. Some code isn't more functional because it used a lot of partial application and many functions :D

Comment: I remember when I started playing with partial application, currying and composition.  I tried hard to make everything point-free.  Some of that still shows in the existence of Ramda functions such as [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) and [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).  Eventually I came to the realization that point-free was a tool to use when it makes the code cleaner and to avoid when it doesn't.

Comment: 100%. I did the same path and got the same conclusion.

Comment: Of course ES6, with destructuring and arrow functions made it much easier to write clean code.

Comment: I can't live without destructuring :D I use this feature everywhere.

Comment: There are several good answers already. I don't know if mine is any better or why the OP accepted it. I'm happy to delete my post if you think it wasn't the best answer.

Comment: @customcommander: Absolutely not. I added mine because I thought additional simplicity was called for. Matias added his to explain how to make the function closer to standard FP concerns. user683133 used her answer to demonstrate that the `Option`/`Maybe` type is not at all esoteric; it's easy to implement and can solve the OP's problem. All of these are useful, but yours is the one the OP found most helpful. Please don't  even consider deleting it. The conversation above is because you write in style both Mathias and I once used but no longer do; not because there's something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically inventing the *Option* type; sometimes called *Maybe*. Using a simple tagged union library like `daggy`, we can implement *Option* -

```
const daggy = require('daggy')

const Option = daggy.taggedSum('Option', {
  Some: ['x'],
  None: [],
})

const { Some, None } = Option

Option.prototype.map = function(f) {
  return this.cata({
    Some: x => Some(f(x)),
    None: _ => this
  })
}

const add = x => y => x + y

console.log
  ( Some(1).map(add(10)) // Some(11)
  , None.map(add(10)) // None
  )
```

We can add a `withDefault` method that allows us to go back to a normal value -

```
Option.prototype.withDefault = function (x) {
  return this.cata({
    Some: x => x,
    None: _ => x
  })
}

console.log
  ( Some(1).map(add(10)).withDefault(0) // 11
  , None.map(add(10)).withDefault(0) // 0
  )
```

Lastly, a constructor to convert normal values to our new Option types -

```
Option.fromNullable = function (x) {
  if (x == null)
    return None
  else
    return Some(x)
}

console.log
  ( Option.fromNullable(1).map(add(10)).withDefault(0) // 11
  , Option.fromNullable(null).map(add(10)).withDefault(0) // 0
  )
```

If you still need to represent this expression as a function, like `a` in your question -

```
const a = R.curry((f, x, y) =>
  Option.fromNullable(x).map(f).withDefault(y))

console.log
  ( a (R.add(8), 5, 2) // 13
  , a (R.add(8), null, 2) // 2
  )
```

Ramda doesn't include a built-in *Option* or *Maybe* but if you're looking for an existing implementation, there are popular modules on npm like [data/maybe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data.maybe).

Comment: Excellent answer... as always.

Comment: @ScottSauyet many thanks, and don't look at the icky style in this post >_< speaking of which, I owe you a draft of a style guide. I'm going to work on that today for you :D

Comment: You don't owe it to me.  I was going to work on it as well and have not found the time.  I would love to see what you come up with, and perhaps sometime next week I'll manage to write my own as well.  But absolutely no hurry.

Comment: @Scott is [this](https://gist.github.com/1hko/af20b4a9fb5128859e3b726d3979459f) enough to get us started? Maybe you can help me build code examples (or paste stuff from my existing answers) to show the style in practical action.

Comment: I opened up [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/) to type up the guide and found this [mystery answer](https://gist.github.com/1hko/ea2220f242c55ff65b887d3d80f2df19) that was never published :( I lost the question it belongs to but it does showcase some of the style guide points well.

Comment: Interesting to see the answer without the question.  Now I want to know what was asked!  ;-)  You're right that this is a nice example of the style.

Comment: Me too! I thought the input would've made it easy to search for but I must've made the input for the demo. I'll contact you off-site to continue the project ^^